# Google Apps Script: Missing Document does exist

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, error-handling

TLDR:
I'm trying to merge two documents into one using google apps script. Google gives an error that the referenced document in DocumentApp.openByID() is either deleted or I don't have read access. Both of these are false - the document does exist, and I am the owner of the document. This makes me believe that Google doesn't allow .openByID() in this case, but it did work for another document that was also referenced in the app.

The Error:

> Exception: Document is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?) at AutoChecklist(Code:107:35)

More about the project:
I'm creating a report to send to clients. All clients will have a cover page and a wrapup page. The pages that go in between depend on what product they choose. What I did was I created every possible page that a client could see, used conditionals to determine which pages a particular customer sees, and merged all of those documents together into one report.

The code: (I've highlighted where the error occurs about 2/3 of the way down)

```
var page_Coverpage = DriveApp.getFileById("1sCWuHq5h4EPMTahCBbL1-kCPNHb7Dky6lMp8vvkK-tA");
var page_checklistMedSupp = DriveApp.getFileById("1Cnpqqk4VvT4FEYBBs9UVrzL48jiNuXYqUqRDOT6k2Bw");
var page_aboutMedSupp_G = DriveApp.getFileById("1ruHXaPGI8-J5v06RxLghiqvXTXp7WMkXyvRhJ7eN7Is");
//set the cover page
  var templateFile = page_Coverpage;
//set the destination folder for the new document
  var response_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1vMahYrFsmU8ExyBFt4EDIluokdOaj4f8");
//Make a copy of the coverpage, name it, and put it in the destination folder
  var newDoc = templateFile.makeCopy(clientName + " Medicare Playbook",response_folder);

//create an array with all of the different documents that need to be on the report
var listofDocs = new Array(newDoc.getId());
if(preferredProduct == "MS-G"|| preferredProduct == "MS-F"||preferredProduct == "MS-N") listofDocs.push(page_checklistMedSupp);
    else if (preferredProduct == "MAPD"|| preferredProduct == "MA Only" || preferredProduct == "DSNP") listofDocs.push(page_checklistMAPD);
    else if (preferredProduct == "Delay Coverage") listofDocs.push(page_checklistDelay);
    else throw new Error("Error: Preferred product response is unknown: "+preferredProduct);

if(preferredProduct == "MS-G") listofDocs.push(page_aboutMedSupp_G);
    else if(preferredProduct == "MS-F") listofDocs.push(page_aboutMedSupp_F);
    else if(preferredProduct == "MS-N") listofDocs.push(page_aboutMedSupp_N);
    else if(preferredProduct == "MAPD") listofDocs.push(page_aboutMAPD);
    else if(preferredProduct == "MA Only") listofDocs.push(page_aboutMAonly);
    else if(preferredProduct == "DSNP") listofDocs.push(page_aboutDSNP);
    else if(preferredProduct == "Delay Coverage") listofDocs.push(page_aboutDelay);
    else throw new Error("Error: Unknown value for preferred product: "+ preferredProduct+". Tried adding 'about' page but there was no 'about' page for this item.");
listofDocs.push(page_promise);

console.log("List of docs are: " + listofDocs); //This has been 100% accurate

//One template document at a time, look at the elements within that template, add them to the newDoc. 

 var basedoc = DocumentApp.openById(listofDocs[0]);
    var body = basedoc.getBody();

for (var i = 1; i < listofDocs.length; ++i){
      console.log("looking for elements in: "+listofDocs[i]);
```

Here is where the error is happening. Notice how .openById was able to run successfully on the cover page a few lines ago, but it won't here.

```
  var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(listofDocs[i]).getBody();
```

---

```
  var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();
  for (var j=0; j < totalElements; ++j){
    var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    console.log("Found an element. Type: "+ type +" in doc: "+ listofDocs[i]);
    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) body.appendParagraph(element);
    else if (type== DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) body.appendTable(element);
    else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) body.appendListItem(element);
    //else throw new Error('Unknown element type: ' + type); (getting rid of this code made it easier to handle 'unsupported' element types)
  }  
}
```

How do you make this error go away?

Full code:

```
//Trigger info...
  /*This will trigger when someone fills out the google form "CLIENT INTAKE FORM" https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSeDQhRtpn2k8ig4PE4PPNUMqRYXMU49YZdYvO4CPk0tyRFJXA/formResponse.
    This particular program/script is triggered only by that form. It was associated with that form by going opening up the form's response sheet, clicking on "extensions", and selecting "Google Apps Script"
    */

function AutoChecklist(e){
// create variables for each response given in the form (provide the reference for each variable's position in the response spreadsheet)
  let clientName = e.values[1];
  let birthday = new Date(e.values[2]);
  let spouseName = e.values[3];
  let spouseDOB = e.values[4];
  let currentCoverage = e.values[5];
  let medicareStatus = e.values[6];
  let ab_enrollmentprocess = e.values[7];
  let preferredProduct = e.values[8];
  let favorites = e.values[9];
  let specialCircumstances = e.values[10];
  let agentNotes1of3 = e.values[11];
  let agentNotes2of3 = e.values[12];
  let agentNotes3of3 = e.values[13];
  let nextAppointment = e.values[14];

//calculate marriage status
//calculate appointment date, time, and location
//after inserting placeholders, change the font from red to black

//Calculate the part B effective / apply dates and the Med Supp apply date:
  //create a variable to be manipulated in place of 'birthday'
    //We're going to use the .setMonth() method. If we ran that on 'birthday' it would change 'birthday' 's value (which needs to be preserved)
    let bdayCopy = new Date(birthday);
  //Calculate the new dates
    let bday65 = new Date(bdayCopy.setMonth(bdayCopy.getMonth()+780));
    let partB_eff = new Date(bdayCopy.setDate(01));
    //Subtract 1 month if the client's birthday is on the 1st.
      if(birthday.getDate()==1){
        partB_eff = new Date(partB_eff.setMonth(partB_eff.getMonth()-1));
        bdayCopy = new Date(bdayCopy.setMonth(bdayCopy.getMonth()-1));
        }
    let applyB = new Date(bdayCopy.setMonth(bdayCopy.getMonth()-3));
    let applyMS = new Date(bdayCopy.setMonth(bdayCopy.getMonth()-4));
  //Format the dates so they look nice
    birthday = birthday.toLocaleDateString('en-us',{year:"numeric",month: "short",day:"numeric"});
    partB_eff = partB_eff.toLocaleDateString('en-us',{year:"numeric",month: "short",day:"numeric"});
    bday65 = bday65.toLocaleDateString('en-us',{year:"numeric",month: "short",day:"numeric"});
    applyB = applyB.toLocaleDateString('en-us',{year:"numeric",month: "short",day:"numeric"});
    applyMS = applyMS.toLocaleDateString('en-us',{year:"numeric",month: "short",day:"numeric"})


// create variables for each file ID - to make it easier to identify in code
  var page_Coverpage = DriveApp.getFileById("1sCWuHq5h4EPMTahCBbL1-kCPNHb7Dky6lMp8vvkK-tA");
  var page_checklistMedSupp = DriveApp.getFileById("1Cnpqqk4VvT4FEYBBs9UVrzL48jiNuXYqUqRDOT6k2Bw");
  var page_checklistMAPD = DriveApp.getFileById("1cIb_2O2uMZS9-6KssfWYBzzL2AV9NIPbAFTFEYowVAg");
  var page_checklistDelay = DriveApp.getFileById("1An5zjB6w2gzqCoyVfPLUU15OOj8f49S5QyCQJEAaIvA")
  var page_aboutMedSupp_G = DriveApp.getFileById("1ruHXaPGI8-J5v06RxLghiqvXTXp7WMkXyvRhJ7eN7Is");
  var page_aboutMedSupp_F = DriveApp.getFileById("1CRox-IkQoBbQYZQhQBCV0TnDf736xJN-0aJ1105l8rg");
  var page_aboutMedSupp_N = DriveApp.getFileById("1wSSSC-YelTipFXnunnVYjfcF8X-jS_FFmUtksFuatfE");
  var page_aboutMAPD = DriveApp.getFileById("1FZXW1hD2lP7sY9UEmOBcHybT9FzP9-jI6fTI9lduSmk");
  var page_aboutDSNP = DriveApp.getFileById("1C_173-EXg-MyDIHVwlNwKw3orWq7IRTIkp3bBbJkhS4");
  var page_aboutMAonly = DriveApp.getFileById("1jGM-feFz6A2f6VTHAdhwTlfq7oN0TKsJgfr-tTMrE_k");
  var page_aboutDelay = DriveApp.getFileById("19i7wfgWc7p0jILQaUtMi89LyEIB-bchbM9AJW3yyiSM");
  var page_promise  = DriveApp.getFileById("197NLSrBr7464JP3rHYG74mhyL79s-mui8HINyPPrLs8");
  

//Set the cover page as the template that will be copied and recreated
  let templateFile = page_Coverpage;

//Set the folder where you want the copy to go
  var response_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1vMahYrFsmU8ExyBFt4EDIluokdOaj4f8");

//Make a copy, name it, and put it in the response folder
  let newDoc = templateFile.makeCopy(clientName + " Medicare Playbook",response_folder);

//Now let's use an array to create a list of optional documents we want to assemble.
  // We know the cover page is always first so let's add it as the first element of the array. 
  var listofDocs = new Array(newDoc.getId());

  // Add the appropriate checklist based on the product chosen by the client
    if(preferredProduct == "MS-G"|| preferredProduct == "MS-F"||preferredProduct == "MS-N") listofDocs.push(page_checklistMedSupp);
    else if (preferredProduct == "MAPD"|| preferredProduct == "MA Only" || preferredProduct == "DSNP") listofDocs.push(page_checklistMAPD);
    else if (preferredProduct == "Delay Coverage") listofDocs.push(page_checklistDelay);
    else throw new Error("Error: Preferred product response is unknown: "+preferredProduct);


  //Add the appropriate 'about' page
    if(preferredProduct == "MS-G") listofDocs.push(page_aboutMedSupp_G);
    else if(preferredProduct == "MS-F") listofDocs.push(page_aboutMedSupp_F);
    else if(preferredProduct == "MS-N") listofDocs.push(page_aboutMedSupp_N);
    else if(preferredProduct == "MAPD") listofDocs.push(page_aboutMAPD);
    else if(preferredProduct == "MA Only") listofDocs.push(page_aboutMAonly);
    else if(preferredProduct == "DSNP") listofDocs.push(page_aboutDSNP);
    else if(preferredProduct == "Delay Coverage") listofDocs.push(page_aboutDelay);
    else throw new Error("Error: Unknown value for preferred product: "+ preferredProduct+". Tried adding 'about' page but there was no 'about' page for this item.");
  //Add on the promise
    listofDocs.push(page_promise);
//log the array which you've built
console.log("List of docs are: "+listofDocs);

// Now take the array of documents we created, and add their elements to the newDoc one element and one doc at a time. 
  // Open up the coverpage and tell the system to look at the body of the doc
    var basedoc = DocumentApp.openById(listofDocs[0]);
    var body = basedoc.getBody();
  //Open the specified document from listofDocs (one at a time),append each element onto the newDoc one at a time. 
    for (var i = 1; i < listofDocs.length; ++i){
      console.log("looking for elements in: "+listofDocs[i]);
      var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(listofDocs[i]).getBody();
      var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();
      for (var j=0; j < totalElements; ++j){
        var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
        var type = element.getType();
        console.log("Found an element. Type: "+ type +" in doc: "+ listofDocs[i]);
        if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) body.appendParagraph(element);
        else if (type== DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) body.appendTable(element);
        else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) body.appendListItem(element);
        //else throw new Error('Unknown element type: ' + type); (getting rid of this code made it easier to handle 'unsupported' element types)
      }  
    }



//Replace placeholders
  //First off, open up the document you want to edit
    let doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  //Now tell the system to look at the body of the document
    var body = doc.getBody();
  //Tell what placeholders to look for and replace
    body.replaceText("{{Client Name}}",clientName);
    body.replaceText("{{Birthday}}", birthday);
    body.replaceText("{{Birthday 65}}",bday65)
    body.replaceText("{{Part B Effective}}",partB_eff);
    body.replaceText("{{Part B Apply Date}}",applyB);
    body.replaceText("{{MedSupp Apply Date}}",applyMS);
    body.replaceText("{{Spouse Name}}",spouseName);
    body.replaceText("{{Spouse DOB}}",spouseDOB);
    body.replaceText("{{Current Coverage}}",currentCoverage);
    body.replaceText("{{Medicare Status}}",medicareStatus);
    body.replaceText("{{Enrollment Process}}",ab_enrollmentprocess);
    body.replaceText("{{Preferred Product}}",preferredProduct);
    body.replaceText("{{Favorites}}",favorites);
    body.replaceText("{{Special Circumstances}}",specialCircumstances);
    body.replaceText("{{Next Appointment}}",nextAppointment);

//Save and close the doc
  doc.saveAndClose();

  console.log("List of docs are: "+listofDocs);

}

/****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
```

Comment: I find it difficult to follow your code.

Comment: in `istofDocs` you are pushing files not ids.  So in `var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(listofDocs[i]).getBody();` listofDocs[i] is not an id.

Comment: @TheWizEd So you're basically saying to change

"var page_aboutMedSupp_G = DriveApp.getFileById("1ruHXaPGI8-J5v06RxLghiqvXTXp7WMkXyvRhJ7eN7Is");"

to "var page aboutMedSupp_G = "1ruHXaPGI8-J5v06RxLghiqvXTXp7WMkXyvRhJ7eN7Is"
?

That makes sense. I would of never caught that.

Comment: This Worked! Thanks for the help!

p.s. I'm new at this so if you have any tips for making the code easier to read on here I am all ears!